# How to use same value, file channel twice in the same process in nextflow

Tags: nextflow

I have a channel of `tuple (val, file)`. I assigned it into two channels `ch1, ch2`. So, both channels have same element and then combined them using `combine` operator. Because, I need the same element twice. But, when I use the combined channel in a process I am getting error that: `input file name collision -- There are multiple files for each of the following file names`. Any help?

Also if I use separately `ch1` and `ch2` like:

```
input:
tuple val(st1), path(mng1) from ch1
tuple val(st2), path(mng2) from ch2
```

The same message `input file name collision -- There are multiple files for each of the following file names`. comes out.

Answer (score 1):

One solution might be to just stage each of the files in separate subdirectories. Note that when working with [multiple input files](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#multiple-input-files), the `*` and `?` wildcards can be used to control the names of the staged files. For example, the `*` wildcard can be used to preserve the original filenames:

```
process example {

    tag { "${st1}:${st2}" }

    debug true

    input:
    tuple val(st1), path(mng1, stageAs: 'dir1/*')
    tuple val(st2), path(mng2, stageAs: 'dir2/*')

    """
    echo "${st1}:${st2}"

    ls -1 "${mng1}"
    ls -1 "${mng2}"
    """
}

workflow {

    Channel
        .fromPath( '/path/to/files/*.txt' )
        .map { tuple( it.baseName, it ) }
        .set { input_ch }


    example( input_ch, input_ch )
}
```

Results:

```
$ nextflow run main.nf 
N E X T F L O W  ~  version 23.04.1
Launching `main.nf` [insane_rosalind] DSL2 - revision: a9c06992eb
executor >  local (3)
[38/28d001] process > example (foo:foo) [100%] 3 of 3 ✔
bar:bar
dir1/bar.txt
dir2/bar.txt

baz:baz
dir1/baz.txt
dir2/baz.txt

foo:foo
dir1/foo.txt
dir2/foo.txt
```

Answer (score -1):

Thank you all. Simple `combine` and `stageAs` resolved the issue.

```
ch1.combine(ch2).set{ch3}
```

then;

```
input:
tuple val(st1), path(mng1, stageAs: "in1/*"), val(st2), path(mng2, stageAs: "in2/*") from ch3
```